# How to reduce the complexity of this code

Tags: c++, optimization

```
1<T<10 (where T is number of test cases)
1<N<1000
```

We have to optimize this code.

I tried with storing factors of all the numbers less than `N` from `1` to `N^2`. But this still gives TLE

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++)
        {
            if ((i * j) % k == 0)
             count++;
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

So I guess it should probably run in O(N^2)

Comment: Which language is it? Please add a tag for it.

Comment: Can you try to find a title that match the general problem at hand here?

Comment: You can make it O(1) by sequentially writing out the calls:
if ((1 * 1) % 1 == 0) count++;
if ((2 * 1) % 1 == 0) count++;
...etc

Comment: This seems to be a problem from a programming contest. Please provide a link to the original problem statement and make sure it's not part of an active contest as that would qualify as cheating.

Comment: So, multiplication is symmetric, `i*j == j*i`, that halves the time immediately.

Comment: Further `i*j` could be lifted out of the inner loop. Compiler might to that anyway, but it's a big win, so doesn't hurt to do it yourself.

Comment: As already mentioned `i*j` is symmetric, which means the two outer loops have to go only to `sqrt(N)`. So instead of having `N·N=N²` iterations of the outer two loops, this cuts those down to `sqrt(N)·sqrt(N)=N`. As far as I can tell this is some kind of variant of a prime number test. So maybe look at prime factorization algorithms, like Sieve of Erastothenes

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to reduce the running time is to use a greatest common divisor (using c++17 here) as follows:

```
#include <numeric>
int main(){
    int N = 1000;
    int count = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k <= N; ++k){
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; ++j){
            int gcd = std::gcd(j,k);
            count += N/(k/gcd);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This has an O(N^2 log(N)) running time.
I believe the complexity can be further reduced with a factorization of k, but the solution may become significantly more complicated.

EDIT: there might be a simple mathematical formula to solve this in O(1). This requires some thought.

Answer (score -1):

Write your code off-line and run it. When running off-line write in a file.

```
fprintf(f,"a[%d]=%d;",n,function(n));
```

where a is a vector of 1001 elements.
Use the generated code.

```
int function(int N) {
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++)
        {
            if ((i * j) % k == 0)
             count++;
        }
    }
}
return count;
}

int main() {
FILE* f = fopen("data.cpp","w");
for(int i=1;i<=1000;++i) {
fprintf(f,"a[%d]=%d;",n,function(n));
if(i%10==0) fprintf(f,"\n");
}
fclose(f);
return 0;
}
```

You run this code on your pc and in data.cpp you will have the new partial source code that you can use for the actual solution.

```
int main() {
int a[1001];
// <- generated code here

// here you will need to use a as a cached value instead of computing

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate I am not able to understand :(

Comment: The basic idea here is that an array lookup is O(1) (e.g. the code that's executed could be `return lookupTable[n];`), and because the N is small the cost of the lookup table will be small (e.g. 4000 bytes - not enough to care about). If you convert your code into a utility that generates the source code for the lookup table you'd only have to run the utility once, then you could include the lookup table in your program and your program will be O(1).

Comment: This answer is stupid, in my opinion. Victor, you know that this is not what the OP is looking for.